# qb-core/clients/loops.lua error Attempt to index a nil value (field 'metadata')

Tags: lua, fivem

I am getting this error again and again I don't know why?

```
CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        local sleep = 0
        if LocalPlayer.state.isLoggedIn then
            sleep = (1000 * 60) * QBCore.Config.UpdateInterval
            TriggerServerEvent('QBCore:UpdatePlayer')
        end
        Wait(sleep)
    end
end)

CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        if LocalPlayer.state.isLoggedIn then
            if (QBCore.PlayerData.metadata['hunger'] <= 0 or QBCore.PlayerData.metadata['thirst'] <= 0) and not QBCore.PlayerData.metadata['isdead'] then
                local ped = PlayerPedId()
                local currentHealth = GetEntityHealth(ped)
                local decreaseThreshold = math.random(5, 10)
                SetEntityHealth(ped, currentHealth - decreaseThreshold)
            end
        end
        Wait(QBCore.Config.StatusInterval)
    end
end)
```

I don't know why the error keeps popping up.

Comment: `QBCore.PlayerData.metadata` is `nil`. Where do you set it? I can't find an assignment to it in your code.